# Java Simple For Loop Not Working

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want the following code to count backwards from 33 to 11 but I can't figure out why this does not work. I'm sure that I'm going to have a Homer Simpson "d'oh" moment when I finally learn the answer, but for now, I'd really appreciate any help.

```
    for(int i = 33; i <= 11; i--)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Comment: I think you meant `i >= 11`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop will execute only as long as `i <= 11`. This is not true the very first time, so the loop never executes. Instead, you want the loop to execute as long as `i >= 11` -- *greater* than 11, not less than 11. With that small correction, your loop will be fine.

Comment: I have to wait for a certain period (around 4 min) before it will allow me to accept.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
for(int i = 33; i >= 11; i--)
{
      System.out.println(i);
}
```